# Почему wmic.exe выводит не полный список установленных программ?

Tags: windows, cmd, wmi

Здравствуйте. Есть задача, выяснить какое ПО установлена на ряде рабочих станций с ОС Windows. Для решения я использовал foreach + wmic

```
set stations=01 02 03    
for %%i in (%stations%) do wmic /node:"station-%%i" product get identifyingnumber,name,vendor,version >> station-%%i.txt
```

И результат превзошел ожидания, я был очень доволен:

```
{CE2CDD62-0124-36CA-84D3-9F4DCF5C5BD9}  Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1                                Microsoft Corporation  3.5.30729       
{1C7ADED3-C371-40DF-A69D-FE0EA73DC394}  Windows Workflow Foundation RU Language Pack                    Microsoft Corporation  3.0.4203.2      
{5B7B4375-6384-4FB2-8273-43CCD528C35E}  Драйверы Guardant                                       Guardant               6.20.108        
{64C2E885-EFDA-4A70-A2CB-BB046A057D75}  1C:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.19.116)                      1C                     8.2.19.116      
{CE460C16-2340-481C-8A94-B6EDB841AD59}  Windows Communication Foundation Language Pack - RUS            Microsoft Corporation  3.0.04506.30    
{3A8C4C87-D460-488A-A0AA-8993F6D355B1}  Radmin Server 3.4                                               Фаматек         3.40.0000       
{061C36B7-08E2-450B-8E84-DD3E8C9FCA19}  Intel(R) Smart Connect Technology 3.0 x86                       Intel                  3.0.41.1571
```

Но, я случайно обнаружил, что этот список не содержит некоторое ПО, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Teamviewer . Это плохо для моей ситуации, так как мне все же нужен полный список. Есть ли решение с wmic.exe или нужно искать альтернативный вариант?

Comment: Чувак, ты сделал мой день. У меня коллега хочет писать диплом как раз по поводу учёта софта через `wmic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Продукты, использующие для установки **НЕ** Windows Installer, выводиться не будут.

Более полные (но тоже неполные) сведения об установленных приложениях можно получить в разделе реестра

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Некоторые приложения вообще ничего не пишут в систему, изображая из себя портабельные версии (хотя свой деинсталлятор и ярлык на него в меню могут и создать). Обычно это те приложения, для установки которых не требуются администраторские права. Часть из них (те, кто посознательнее) пишет сведения о себе в аналогичную ветку, но в кусте HKCU.

Comment: При помощи powershell или cmd можно полить информацию из реестра удаленной ОС ?

Comment: Можно выгрузить ветку в текстовый файл и потом распарсить её, извлекая нужные токены.

Comment: @m2_viktor: Утилита `reg`, насколько я помню, может работать с удалённым реестром.

Comment: Может. Правда, не со всеми ветками.

Comment: К сожалению я обнаружил множество ПО которого нет по указанному пути не в HKLM, не в HKCU. Но при этом это ПО есть в списке "приложения и компоненты" в панели управления.

Comment: @m2_viktor Это бесполезное почти сообщение. Сделайте поиск по реестру, найдите, где лежит информация о таком ПО - полезность возрастёт не в разы - на порядок.